# Xamarins forms Geolocalisation does not work on android real device but woks on emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement  [xamarin essential Geolocalisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android).

I would like to get the latitude and longitude of the phone

I Have followed the Microsoft tutorial. It works on emulator and works on physical device when deployed from Visual studio, but it does not work when downloaded from Google Play  (Android version 8,9,10)

Here is my code :

```
var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

Location location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);
    
if (location != null)
{
    GetLocation(location);
}else{
    Console.WriteLine("not working");
}
```

Comment: Does your device have GPS?   Have you granted permissions for GPS to the app?  Have you followed the extensive docs on setting up permissions, etc for Android?  Have you checked for any exceptions?  Have you tried running the Essentials sample app?

Comment: I have tcheked all of them. It is working on my emulator in many devices  but not on real devices (huawei,samsung) and thoses devices have Google map that is working for localisation. And I cannot understand why localisation  is not working of the app

Comment: What about testing with the Essentials sample app?  Or checking the log files for relevant messages?

Comment: I I will check the log files because I cannot post the Essentails sample app on Google Play

Comment: What does Google Play have to do with it?  Why aren't you doing device testing directly from VS?

Comment: @Jason on visual studio when running the  emulator it is working

Comment: You can deploy to a physical device from VS.  You do not have to use Google Play.  This allows you to debug directly on hardware.

Comment: when depoying on physical device it is working ,but it is not working when deploy on google play

Comment: Have you tried `Geolocation.GetLocationAsync();`? That is, no request - let it default to whatever it can do. Similarly, have you tried the most generous possible request: low accuracy, extremely long timeout or zero timeout for infinity?  To rule out other possible problems. These shouldn't matter, given that it works when you deploy from VS to that same device - but under the circumstances, its best to rule out anything we can. Another possibility: maybe the geolocation - on device - can't give you an accurate answer quickly **on the first call**. Maybe that is different when debugging.

Comment: 1) Please update your question to indicate that it works on a physical device, when deployed from VS, but not when downloaded from Google Play **to the same device**, if that is true. 2) Did you test a **RELEASE build,** deployed from VS?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve 1) I have updated the question 2) I have test on release and it works

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I will try the default Geolocation.GetLocationAsync();

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve  Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(); it is not working

Comment: What's your Xamarin.Essentials version ?Did you try to use the latest version ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I have the version 1.6.1 and I am installing the version 1.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that when I was deploying on Android for some phone the coordinate was written with coma and some time with point.

That why it was not displaying

Thanks everybody